# Javascript function create element conditional

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer, however I have been trying to look at similar samples to come up with my own version, here is what I am trying to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var advertContainer = null;
    var adblocked = null;

function Checkads() {
    if ($('.wp_bannerize').height() == 0) {
    var adblocked = document.createElement("span");
    var adnotice  = document.createTextNode("Please support our website by enabling ads");
    adblocked.appendChild(adnotice);
    var advertContainer = document.getElementById("wp_bannerize");
    advertContainer.appendChild(adblocked);
    };
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    Checkads();
});
</script>
```

However I am getting an error : Uncaught Type error:  Cannot call method append child "null"

Can anyone help me fix it

**Update**

Here is the much nicer and better code, however the text can only be visible in the source code and not on the website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkads() {
    if ($('.wp_bannerize').height() == 0) {
    $('<div id="adnotice">').text('Please support our website by enabling ads').appendTo('.wp_bannerize');
    };
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkads();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does `document.getElementById("wp_bannerize")` exist?

Comment: The message means that advertContainer is null, meaning no element exists with an id of `wp_bannerize`.

Comment: yes it exist but is not an id, its a class actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a class selector with jQuery:

```
$('.wp_bannerize')
```

But an ID selector with the native DOM method:

```
document.getElementById("wp_bannerize");
```

They're not the same. To fix your script, replace `getElementById('wp_bannerize')` with `getElementsByClassName('wp_bannerize')[0]`, or just do it with jQuery:

```
if ($('.wp_bannerize').height() == 0) {
    $('<span>').text('Please support our website by enabling ads').appendTo('.wp_bannerize');
}
```

Comment: replacing getElementBy it with an class selector?

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName` doesn't exist in IE8. So, stick to jQuery.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Wow, I completely forgot about that.

Comment: interesting stuff guys, I need to do research about jquery and javascrupt then i dont know the difference, in the mean time, where do I add the third recommended code, seems that i have mixed up languages here

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: jQuery is JavaScript. It's not a separate language.

Comment: So do i still need to create the span element using native dom?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos javascript is the language. It doesn't know anything about `$` or `document` except they are valid identifiers. The browser environment (still called "javascript") defines `document` and its various methods. The problem is, various browsers define various methods in their environment. Thus, you have to deal with browsers that don't follow the spec (\*cough\*IE\*cough\*). JQuery is a library for javascript. It wraps around the DOM API provided by the browser and provides methods that are shorter in name, more consistent and cross-browser compatible.

Comment: I am looking at the source code and I can see that it is working indeed it appends and shows the message, but is not visible in the the website, I can only see it in the source code, I tried adding background and size and even changing it to DIV and adding and ID but i cant see the message in the front end.

Comment: Actually guys, how can I create a new element and list it below a certain other element, or is this the same as appending?